# ActionScript and SQLite parameters on Select using Like

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, sqlite, parameters, sql-like

I tried looking on google but without luck...

I have a `SELECT SQLStatement` and I want to use the `LIKE` operator but the parameters won't work and the query give me an error

```
    public function getUsersList(username:String):SQLStatement
    {           
        selectRecord= new SQLStatement();
        selectRecord.sqlConnection = connection;                                
        selectRecord.text =
            "SELECT id_user, username,password,profile,leg_cliente " +
            "FROM userlist  " +
            "WHERE username like '%:username%'";            
        selectRecord.parameters[":username"] = username;

        return selectRecord;
    }
```

The error I got is

> ':username' parameter name(s) found in parameters property but not in
>   the SQL specified.

Comment: Does the query work from SQLiteManager Firefox extension?

Comment: yes the problem is not the `like` keyword, but the fact that AS3 does not find the parameters between `%`

Comment: Parameters even just like that in the single-quotes break AS3's inbuilt code. See my work-around

Comment: What about question marks (?) instead of named params? What happens if you put the % in the 'username' variable instead of the statement?

Comment: It works putting the % in the username variable... thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved putting the wildcard `%` in the parameters instead of the statement...

```
        selectRecord.text =
            "SELECT id_user, username,password,profile,leg_cliente " +
            "FROM userlist  " +
            "WHERE username like :username";            
        selectRecord.parameters[":username"] = "%"+ username+"%";
```

The starting problem was triggered because the query was like

```
    selectRecord.text =
        "SELECT id_user, username,password,profile,leg_cliente " +
        "FROM userlist  " +
        "WHERE username like '%:username%'";
```

Putting the single quote in the statement won't let the statement to set the parameter, I suppose because the parameter key (in statement.text) is seen as a text and not a parameter itself...

Comment: Weird. For me, `SELECT * from userlist WHERE username=':username'` does not work, even when selectRecord.parameters[":username"] has just `jon` instead of `%jon%`

Comment: you don't have to put the single quote in sqlstatement, try with this query `SELECT * from userlist WHERE username=:username` and it should works well!

Comment: ahhh alright. So does it work WITH the % but without the ' e.g. `"WHERE username like %:username%"; `

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird issue I've been stuck with for quite some time now. One solution I've used is like this:

```
var statementText:String="SELECT id_user, username,password,profile,leg_cliente " +
        "FROM userlist  " +
        "WHERE username like '%:username%'";

var params:Dictionary=new Dictionary();
params[":username"] = username;


for(var key:Object in params) {
    while(statementText.indexOf(key.toString()) >= 0) {
        statementText= statementText.replace(key, params[key]);
    }   
}

selectRecord.text = statementText;
```

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of named parameters? I mean, it would make your code vulnerable to SQL injection again.

Comment: Now that you say so, yeah it does. :) Anyhow, that's the only thing that worked for me. What do you recommend @RIAstar ?

Comment: Haven't run into the issue yet, so I don't have a solution ready. But I made some suggestions in the main comment thread.